# Can App Engine Flexible Environment connect to a persistent disk?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to run one process on App Engine Flexible Environment that needs access to a traditional file system to save information that survives restarts.

Is this possible? (I only see documentation for ephemeral disks.) Are there any workarounds if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the appengine flexible environment does give us access to disk access, it is not yet configurable as persistent disk. Have you considered using Cloud Storage if you need such persistence?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would love to use cloud storage but I would have to somehow mount it so it could be accessed as a standard file system. The process I want to run uses the norman file access APIs to read and write data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **gcsfuse** to mount Cloud Storage bucket as local filesystem on either Google Cloud Run or Google App Engine. This approach has some latency limitations and caveats in terms of nested directories though. You can learn more about this here:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md